# Feeding a dependent plant on shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, agriculture, water

Suppose someone keeps a plant that must be watered daily in order for it to survive. May that person water the plant on Shabbat?  Note that this is definitely allowed and even *required* for pet animals who must be fed daily; however, plants seem to me as though they might be different in this regard.

Comment: Asur MiDeOraitha.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason not to water an animal is that it was banned by rabbis because it takes too much time and effort (*tircha*) (e.g., [*Aruch Hashulchan* 324](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%93):1). They built exceptions into the ban in cases of need (such as, usually, when the animal depends on you for food) (e.g., 324 passim). The reason not to water a plant is because God said you can't make a plant grow on *Shabas* (e.g., [336](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%95):2). He didn't build in any exception for your own plants.

That said, consult your rabbi if this is a practical question for you, rather than relying on what you read on this site.